# How do I cache slow webpages for longer?

Tags: google-chrome, performance, webpage, browser-cache, confluence

I regularly access web pages which rarely change, but which load slowly. They are pages of notes on an internal company wiki (confluence).

Is there a plugin for Chrome or Firefox which will allow me to cache pages for a specified amount of time, when I click a button? And ideally let me invalidate the cache on demand if I know/suspect the page has changed.

Comment: I'd prefer to address the cause rather than the symptoms. Adjusting the caching directives on the server is better than overriding them at the client. Speeding up the service is better still.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick: ISTM that he cannot control the entire communication link. Remember, the bottleneck can be on the remote server (which cannot be controlled by the OP - because otherwise what would be the point of his question? - and the bottleneck can be also hardware-related like a slow disk, NIC, CPU etc.) and/or any link between them (for ex. he cannot change the LAN hardware). Yes, this happens. It happened also to me. But the solution isn't to thinker with the browser's cache. See my response.

Answer (score 0):

**The simplest way** is to use `File | Save As...` in order to save the page as *txt*, *html*, *html complete* or even *mht* which is the preferred way if your browser supports it.

However, this saves only the current page and sometimes isn't so easy to manage the saved files.

Another solution is by using some **Firefox extensions** like [Scrapbook](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/427) or similar which will give you more power than the above solution.

The 3rd way - if you need to download entire sites (or part of them) and need more power and flexibility - is by using **offline browsers** which are separate programs but they do a much better job in getting offline the content you want. One of the most well-known free offline browser is [HTTrack](http://www.httrack.com/) but there are [other programs](http://www.ilovefreesoftware.com/14/featured/5-free-offline-browsers-to-browse-websites-offline.html) too.